# Getting "The service method is not found error" in Bing Maps

Tags: asp.net, web-services, bing-maps

We are using geocoding service to get geocodeAddress (latitude/longitude) but we are getting the "The service method is not found" error. Below are my code.

```
 public static double[] GeocodeAddress(string address, string virtualearthKey)
        {
            net.virtualearth.dev.GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new net.virtualearth.dev.GeocodeRequest
            {
                // Set the credentials using a valid Bing Maps key
                Credentials = new net.virtualearth.dev.Credentials { ApplicationId = virtualearthKey },
                // Set the full address query
                Query = address                
            };

            // Set the options to only return high confidence results 
            net.virtualearth.dev.ConfidenceFilter[] filters = new net.virtualearth.dev.ConfidenceFilter[1];
            filters[0] = new net.virtualearth.dev.ConfidenceFilter
            {
                MinimumConfidence = net.virtualearth.dev.Confidence.High
            };

            // Add the filters to the options
            net.virtualearth.dev.GeocodeOptions geocodeOptions = new net.virtualearth.dev.GeocodeOptions { Filters = filters };
            geocodeRequest.Options = geocodeOptions;

            // Make the geocode request
            net.virtualearth.dev.GeocodeService geocodeService = new net.virtualearth.dev.GeocodeService();
            net.virtualearth.dev.GeocodeResponse geocodeResponse = geocodeService.Geocode(geocodeRequest);

            if (geocodeResponse.Results.Length > 0)
            {
                return new[] { geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Latitude, geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Longitude };
            }

            return new double[] { };
        } // GeocodeAddress
```

Key is used for URL for bing map geocode service in we.config

```
<add key="net.virtualearth.dev.GeocodeService" value="http://dev.virtualearth.net/webservices/v1/geocodeservice/GeocodeService.svc" />
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: It appears that I've asked you to refrain from begging and pleading several times before. It would be ideal to desist not only because that's basic manners, but to save your questions from downvotes. Readers do not like folks thinking their questions are more important than other people's questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to use the old Virtual Earth SOAP Services which were deprecated and shut down last year. These were replaced by the Bing Maps REST services 7 or 8 years ago. Since you are working in .NET, take a look at the Bing Maps .NET REST Toolkit. It makes it easy to use the REST services in .NET. There is a NuGet package available as well. You can find details here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit

Once you have the NuGet package added to your project, you can geocode like this:

```
//Create a request.
var request = new GeocodeRequest()
{
    Query = "New York, NY",
    IncludeIso2 = true,
    IncludeNeighborhood = true,
    MaxResults = 25,
    BingMapsKey = "YOUR_BING_MAPS_KEY"
};

//Execute the request.
var response = await request.Execute();

if(response != null && 
    response.ResourceSets != null && 
    response.ResourceSets.Length > 0 && 
    response.ResourceSets[0].Resources != null && 
    response.ResourceSets[0].Resources.Length > 0)
{
    var result = response.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location;

    //Do something with the result.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it was really helpful.